# Where is the favicon defined for this site?

Tags: html, favicon

Looking at the source for Skype.com, I cannot find any `<link rel="shortcut icon">` tag (or anything similar), and yet, the icon is clearly showing up in FireFox. Where are they defining the favicon?

- http://www.skype.com/en/ (right click to view source)

Comment: http://www.skype.com/favicon.ico

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless otherwise defined, the browser will look for the favicon in the root with the filename `favicon.ico`

- [www.skype.com/favicon.ico](http://www.skype.com/favicon.ico)

As far as I know you need the exact name `favicon.ico` for the browser to detect it. That might be different in other browsers, but if you want to use `.png` instead of `.ico` for some reason it would be safer to call it out manually for browser compatibility even if the newer browsers are seeing it.

Comment: Does that only apply to `ico` files, or will browsers also check for `favicon.png` if none is defined in the page's source?

Comment: Thanks, could you add that extra information to the answer, and I will go ahead and accept it?

Answer (score 4):

By default browsers will look in the root web directory for `favicon.ico` when a path is not explicitly specified by a `<link>` tag.

Comment: Does that only apply to `ico` files, or will browsers also check for `favicon.png` if none is defined in the page's source?

Comment: Last I heard it was only .ico files but modern browsers *might* look for a variety of file types. I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: According to my server logs, they are still only looking for favicon.ico (I don't have any favicon.png, so a lot of 404's would be logged, lol.)